# How to recursively rsync a tree excluding the node_modules dir no matter where it appears in the tree

Tags: rsync

I'm currently using rsync to backup my development drive. In it I have many projects with a `node_modules` directory. This can happen recursively in any part of the tree. I'm trying to get rsync to exclude this dir completely no matter where it appears in the tree except that I'm only being able to exclude it in the top most branch.

I thought that by using a glob pattern in the exclude flag I would be able to achieve this but I'm not being able to.

EDIT: Here's the command I'm using:

```bsh
rsync -avrt --no-whole-file --inplace --delete --exclude-from ~/backup_scripts/exclude_list . /Volumes/Backups
```

The file `~/backup_scripts/exclude_list` contains:

```
Library/Application Support/Spotify/PersistentCache/Storage/
Library/Application Support/Steam/appcache/httpcache/
Library/Application Support/Steam/config/htmlcache/
Library/Caches/
Library/Logs/
.bash_sessions/
.npm/
.composer/
.pdepend/
.cocoapods/
node_modules
```

Also tried `*/node_modules` and `node_modules/*` to no avail.

Comment: What's the actual command you're using?

Comment: @muru I've updated the answer with an example.